# Extracting text from ftp address

Tags: c#, text, ftp, extract, lastindexof

I'm creating small FTP Client and stuck on small issue, can you help me to sort it out please.

So I'm taking text from comboBox1.Text witch is lets say "/test/sql/it/"
But for creating new directory I need to extract "it" and "/test/sql/"
"it" as new directory name and "/test/sql/" location for creating new folder.

For second part I can use:

```
string s = comboBox1.Text;
        s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('/'));
        s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf('/'));
        s = s + "/";
        MessageBox.Show(s);
        //result "/test/sql/"
```

But how to get first part "it" any one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
string s = comboBox1.Text;
string path_s = Path.GetFileName( Path.GetDirectoryName( path ) );
```

The inner call to GetDirectoryName will return the full path, while the outer call to GetFileName() will return the last path component - which will be the folder name.

Comment: Thanks works nice just one correction:
string s = comboBox1.Text; to string path = comboBox1.Text;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string path = "/test/sql/it/";
string[] directories = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string lastDir = directories.Last();
```

Comment: Having a bit difficulties:
directories.Last();
Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
.+(/.+/)$
```

That will give you `/it/`in group 1.
If you don't want the slashes, use this regex instead:

```
.+/(.+)/$
```

Comment: Something like this:
Match output = Regex.Match(comboBox_RemotePatch.Text, ".+(/.+/)$");